# Shiny Server Pro vs shinyapps.io Standard for password authentication

Tags: r, shiny, rstudio, shinyapps

I am designing a Shiny app that will perform differently for different users. This article (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/permissions.html) describes how to do it on Shiny Server Pro and RStudio Connect; however, that pricing tier is not an option for me.

Does anyone know, is there a way to get similar performance on shinyapps.io with the Standard plan? That plan includes password authentication (https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/authentication-and-user-management.html). So my question is, would I be able to access the username through `session$clientData`, as described in this article? (https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/client-data.html)

If not, I'm prepared to write the authentication code into the app server, like this (https://github.com/treysp/shiny_password), which has worked for me in the past. The data is not too sensitive. But I was hoping for something a little less "hackish." Thanks!

Comment: yes you can access session$user if the app is set to private in shinyapps.io. You get the email of the user. You would then need a database or a look up table to determine the authentication level for the user with that particular email id. https://docs.rstudio.com/shinyapps.io/metrics.html#tracking-user-and-session-information

Comment: Thanks @Sada93, that's great news. I currently have only the Starter plan, so I will upgrade to Standard and do some testing.